# Scala ordered priority queue that always has the lowest number as the head, ascending order

Tags: scala, sorting, heap, priority-queue

I'd like to get a code sample that accomplishes ascending ordering of items in a priority queue.

I'd like to store `Tuple2(Int, String)` inside a priority queue so that it is ordered by the first element of the tuple in ascending order.
If my priority queue is called `pq` and I call `pq.head` I'd like to get the tuple with the lowest number, same thing with calling `pq.dequeue`.

```
scala> val pq = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, String)]()
pq: scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, String)] = PriorityQueue()

scala> pq += Tuple2(8, "eight")
res60: pq.type = PriorityQueue((8,eight))

scala> pq += Tuple2(4, "four")
res61: pq.type = PriorityQueue((8,eight), (4,four))

scala> pq += Tuple2(7, "seven")
res62: pq.type = PriorityQueue((8,eight), (4,four), (7,seven))
```

How to apply ascending ordering by first element at time of insertion to the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

`PriorityQueue.apply` and `PriorityQueue.empty` both take an implicit `Ordering` instance that will be used to order the contents—the head will be the "largest" value according to that ordering. You're getting the default one for tuples, which is a lexicographic ordering on the elements of the tuple, which isn't what you want, since it'll make the tuple with the largest first element the head.

There are a couple of ways you can solve this issue. The easiest is just to call `.reverse` on your queue, which will give you a new queue with the same contents but the opposite ordering, which means the tuple with the lowest value will be the head.

You can also provide your own ordering when creating the queue:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue

val pq = PriorityQueue.empty[(Int, String)](
  implicitly[Ordering[(Int, String)]].reverse
)
```

Or if you explicitly don't want the second element to be consulted:

```
val pq = PriorityQueue.empty[(Int, String)](
  Ordering.by((_: (Int, String))._1).reverse
)
```

This is possibly a little more efficient than reversing the queue, but probably not enough to worry about, so you should just choose the approach that you find most elegant.

Comment: I used the second example and it works, thanks. In that example, is the entire queue reversed every time an item is inserted or does ordering happen only for the element being inserted?

Comment: Not every time—the queue will always be ordered according to the ordering you provide when you create it (the only thing that's reversed is the ordering instance, and that's created once).

Comment: Like the explicit way to declare the ordering: PriorityQueue.empty[A](Ordering[A]), thanks! Don't like the constructor with implicit parameter

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is reversing the implicit ordering, you could just reverse the queue right away:

```
val pq = PriorityQueue.empty[(Int, String)].reverse
```

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is to mention ordering of the queue items. The following code will serve the purpose.

```
  def ascendingOrder(tuple2: (Int, String)) = -tuple2._1
  val pq = PriorityQueue[(Int, String)]()(Ordering.by(ascendingOrder))
  pq += Tuple2(8, "eight")
  pq += Tuple2(4, "four")
  pq += Tuple2(7, "seven")
  for (i <- 1 to 3) (println(pq.dequeue()))
```

Avoid using `reverse` as it will create unnecessary overheads.

Answer (score 0):

From the scaladoc:

> Only the `dequeue` and `dequeueAll` methods will return methods in priority order (while removing elements from the heap).  Standard collection methods including `drop` and `iterator` will remove or traverse the heap in whichever order seems most convenient.

That caveat seems to also apply to `.head`, but `.dequeue` returns elements in order.

The default ordering is descending (since the highest priority comes out first), but you can explicitly pass a reversed order when constructing:

```
val normalOrder = implicitly[Ordering[(Int, String)]]
val reversedOrder = Ordering.reverse(normalOrder)
val pq = scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue[(Int, String)](reversedOrder)
```

Comment: The API documentation for `head` explicitly says "Returns the element with the highest priority in the queue".

Comment: So can we be confident that head and dequeue will return the same element, always?

Comment: @o'aoughrouer Yes, that's the contract specified in the documentation.